# Cleaning Data Before SVM

Tags: svm, data-preprocessing

I want to classify diabetic retinopathy grades using SVM. I have 32 extracted features, and those features won't all be used in classification stage. Before entering feature selection, I want to clean the data to improve the correlation and classification accuracy. If i have normal and abnormal data, how do i find and delete the uncorrelated normal data in my dataframe? is there any specific method? thank you!